# Unable to use GWT-RPC in super dev mode after setting -Dgwt.codeserver.port=9876

Tags: gwt, gwt-rpc

I am using **SUPER DEV MODE** to run my existing project (**built using GWT SDk 2.5.0**).
Everything works fine,but only problem is that **I am unable to make calls to my RPCs**.I tried the solution i.e setting **-Dgwt.codeserver.port=9876 in VM arguments**,but still I am unable to call RPCs.It gives me following exception:-

```
[WARN] springGwtRemoteServiceServlet: An IncompatibleRemoteServiceException was thrown while processing this call.
com.google.gwt.user.client.rpc.IncompatibleRemoteServiceException: Type 'com.xxx.appcore.client.ui.ActionMode' was not assignable to 'com.google.gwt.user.client.rpc.IsSerializable' and did not have a custom field serializer. For security purposes, this type will not be deserialized.
    at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.RPC.decodeRequest(RPC.java:323)
    at org.spring4gwt.server.SpringGwtRemoteServiceServlet.processCall(SpringGwtRemoteServiceServlet.java:32)
    at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.RemoteServiceServlet.processPost(RemoteServiceServlet.java:248)
    at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.AbstractRemoteServiceServlet.doPost(AbstractRemoteServiceServlet.java:62)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:637)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:487)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.handle(ServletHandler.java:362)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:216)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.SessionHandler.handle(SessionHandler.java:181)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.handle(ContextHandler.java:729)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.handle(WebAppContext.java:405)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:152)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.RequestLogHandler.handle(RequestLogHandler.java:49)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:152)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.Server.handle(Server.java:324)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handleRequest(HttpConnection.java:505)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection$RequestHandler.content(HttpConnection.java:843)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseNext(HttpParser.java:647)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseAvailable(HttpParser.java:211)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handle(HttpConnection.java:380)
    at org.mortbay.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:395)
    at org.mortbay.thread.QueuedThreadPool$PoolThread.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:488)
Caused by: com.google.gwt.user.client.rpc.SerializationException: Type 'com.lbtmind.appcore.client.ui.ActionMode' was not assignable to 'com.google.gwt.user.client.rpc.IsSerializable' and did not have a custom field serializer. For security purposes, this type will not be deserialized.
    at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.impl.LegacySerializationPolicy.validateDeserialize(LegacySerializationPolicy.java:127)
    at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.impl.ServerSerializationStreamReader.deserialize(ServerSerializationStreamReader.java:651)
    at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.impl.ServerSerializationStreamReader.readObject(ServerSerializationStreamReader.java:567)
    at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.impl.ServerSerializationStreamReader$ValueReader$8.readValue(ServerSerializationStreamReader.java:140)
    at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.impl.ServerSerializationStreamReader.deserializeValue(ServerSerializationStreamReader.java:425)
    at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.impl.ServerSerializationStreamReader.deserializeClass(ServerSerializationStreamReader.java:807)
    at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.impl.ServerSerializationStreamReader.deserializeImpl(ServerSerializationStreamReader.java:878)
    at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.impl.ServerSerializationStreamReader.deserialize(ServerSerializationStreamReader.java:662)
    at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.impl.ServerSerializationStreamReader.readObject(ServerSerializationStreamReader.java:567)
    at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.core.java.util.Collection_ServerCustomFieldSerializerBase.deserialize(Collection_ServerCustomFieldSerializerBase.java:38)
    at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.core.java.util.ArrayList_ServerCustomFieldSerializer.deserialize(ArrayList_ServerCustomFieldSerializer.java:40)
    at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.core.java.util.ArrayList_ServerCustomFieldSerializer.deserializeInstance(ArrayList_ServerCustomFieldSerializer.java:54)
    at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.core.java.util.ArrayList_ServerCustomFieldSerializer.deserializeInstance(ArrayList_ServerCustomFieldSerializer.java:33)
    at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.impl.ServerSerializationStreamReader.deserializeImpl(ServerSerializationStreamReader.java:859)
    at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.impl.ServerSerializationStreamReader.deserialize(ServerSerializationStreamReader.java:662)
    at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.impl.ServerSerializationStreamReader.readObject(ServerSerializationStreamReader.java:567)
    at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.impl.ServerSerializationStreamReader$ValueReader$8.readValue(ServerSerializationStreamReader.java:140)
    at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.impl.ServerSerializationStreamReader.deserializeValue(ServerSerializationStreamReader.java:425)
    at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.impl.ServerSerializationStreamReader.deserializeClass(ServerSerializationStreamReader.java:807)
    at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.impl.ServerSerializationStreamReader.deserializeImpl(ServerSerializationStreamReader.java:878)
    at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.impl.ServerSerializationStreamReader.deserialize(ServerSerializationStreamReader.java:662)
    at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.impl.ServerSerializationStreamReader.readObject(ServerSerializationStreamReader.java:567)
    at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.impl.ServerSerializationStreamReader$ValueReader$8.readValue(ServerSerializationStreamReader.java:140)
    at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.impl.ServerSerializationStreamReader.deserializeValue(ServerSerializationStreamReader.java:425)
    at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.RPC.decodeRequest(RPC.java:312)
    ... 22 more
```

Please provide me the solution to solve this problem.
Thanx well in advance..!!

Answer (score 1):

`-Dgwt.codeserver.port` has only been introduced in GWT 2.6.

For older versions, you can manually copy the serialization policies from the CodeServer to your server hosting the servlets; or override `doGetSerializationPolicy` to load it *via* HTTP from the CodeServer (at `http://localhost:9876/`). Have a look at the code from a 2.6+ version of GWT for an example of how to do it.
…though honestly it's probably easier to just update to GWT 2.6.1 or, even better, 2.7.0.

Comment: :Thank you for information,but I don't know how to manually set serialization policies.I mean from where should i copy them and where to paste or modify.Can you please provide me steps??

Comment: Open the CodeServer page at `http://localhost:9876`, you should find them here; they're `.gwt.rpc` files. BTW, I just remember an alternative; updating my answer.

Comment: :- I tried your solution i.e I upgraded my SDK to 2.6.1 but now its giving me following error

Comment: Unable to start embedded HTTP server
[ERROR] shell failed in doStartupServer method
java.lang.SecurityException: sealing violation: package javax.servlet is sealed
 at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:244)
 at java

Comment: :I resolved above ERROR by moving SDK location above in the classpath.Now project compiles and run but still I am getting same Error i.e I am unable to call my RPCs. Please help me.

Comment: Also just I want to tell that I am Using both client and server on my localhost.(That's why I was asking where to copy paste gwt.rpc)

Answer (score 0):

Check your class `com.lbtmind.appcore.client.ui.ActionMode`.

- Either it doesn't implement `java.lang.Serializable` or `com.google.gwt.user.client.isSerializable`
- or it has no public no-arg constructor
- or your widgetset needs to be recompiled
- or you need to update the WEB-INF/lib/gwt-servlet.jar to the version you built with

Comment: :Thanx for your prompt reply.Actually com.lbtmind.appcore.client.ui.ActionMode is not a class its a enum.So can't implement any interface.Also i recompiled and updated gwt-servlet.jar,but still the problem is same.I don't think there is any problem in coding because the same project runs perfectly on normal Dev Mode.The exception is occuring after using Super Dev Mode.

Comment: @vishalsonawane  are you sure superdevmode and normal mode are on same GWT version?

Comment: @geetrt3:Yes I am sure.I am conerting my existing code to run it in Super Dev Mode and I have followed all the necessary steps for the same.Everything works fine i.e project compiles and runs in Super Dev Mode,but when i run project and try to use RPC call,it gives me exception.

Comment: can you please post 1) console output of superdev mode startup 2) class path entries of your superdev mode (e.g. in eclipse "run configurations... / your superdev runconfig / class path tab" 3) build path entries of your gwt project (e.g. in eclipse "your project / properties / build path / libraries")

Comment: I had this exact same error a while back, I am pretty sure it was a rogue older gwt jar being included on the classpath. I was scratching my head for a while but I think it was the gwt-servlet jar was being included twice. Double check your classpath and make sure you only have the newest jars available on deployment.

Comment: @ChrisHinshaw-Thanx for reply.I checked my included jars and there are no duplicates.I have also imported the same gwt-servlet jar from the SDK I am Using.Any other solutions??